# Listview elements being shifted right

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a listview element with 14 columns, and i seems like everything is being read into the listview as it should, however, it is all shifted 1 column to the right? [image: Here is a picture of it:]

This is my code:

```cs
listView2.Items.Clear();
List<string> Event = new List<string>();
List<string> Currency = new List<string>();
List<string> Ammount = new List<string>();
List<string> DateAndTime = new List<string>();
List<string> customerName = new List<string>();
List<string> mpnumber = new List<string>();
List<string> Comment = new List<string>();
List<string> transactionid = new List<string>();
List<string> transferid = new List<string>();
List<string> paymentpoint = new List<string>();
List<string> myshopnumber = new List<string>();
List<string> Bankaccount = new List<string>();
List<string> Date = new List<string>();
List<string> time = new List<string>();

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    Event.Add(item.SubItems[0].Text);
    Currency.Add(item.SubItems[1].Text);
    Ammount.Add(item.SubItems[2].Text);
    DateAndTime.Add(item.SubItems[3].Text);
    customerName.Add(item.SubItems[4].Text);
    mpnumber.Add(item.SubItems[5].Text);
    Comment.Add(item.SubItems[6].Text);
    transactionid.Add(item.SubItems[7].Text);
    transferid.Add(item.SubItems[8].Text);
    paymentpoint.Add(item.SubItems[9].Text);
    myshopnumber.Add(item.SubItems[10].Text);
    Bankaccount.Add(item.SubItems[11].Text);
    Date.Add(item.SubItems[12].Text);
    time.Add(item.SubItems[13].Text);
}

List<int> indexOfRandom = new List<int>();
var random = new Random();
var lower = 0;
var upper = Event.Count;

for (int k = 0; k < numberOfRandoms; k++)
{
    var rannum = random.Next(lower, upper);
    indexOfRandom.Add(rannum);
}
listView2.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRandoms; i++)
{
    ListViewItem randomrows = new ListViewItem();
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(Event[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(Currency[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(Ammount[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(DateAndTime[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(customerName[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(mpnumber[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(Comment[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(transactionid[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(transferid[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(paymentpoint[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(myshopnumber[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(Bankaccount[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(Date[i]);
    randomrows.SubItems.Add(time[i]);
    listView2.Items.Add(randomrows);
}
listView2.EndUpdate();
```

Hope the question makes sense, feel free to ask me for information

My listview1 is essentially a long list of transactions that works well, however it seems to shift it all 1 to the right when i transfer it to listview2?

Comment: *"When performing operations on subitems in the collection, be sure to reference index position `1` instead of `0` to make changes to the first subitem."*   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: where are you setting this variable: numberOfRandoms

Comment: The 1st column is filled with the ListViewItem.Text property, the sub-items start at the 2nd column.  So it needs to be ListViewItem randomrows = new ListViewItem(Event[i]); etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was posted by @hansPassant, it was:
"The 1st column is filled with the ListViewItem.Text property, the sub-items start at the 2nd column. So it needs to be ListViewItem randomrows = new ListViewItem(Event[i]); etc..."